# open activity when select item from spinner and press the button

Tags: java, android-studio, button, spinner

I don't know where is the problem.When I run the app, the spinner doesn't exist.
I am new in adroid studio and i'll glad to see where the mistake.

```
Spinner spin1;
Button but11;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_program_autobuz);


    spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProgramAutobuz.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LiniiAutobuz));

    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin1.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    but11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but11);
    but11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String text = spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (text.equals("101")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramAutobuz.this, Orar101.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (text.equals("102")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramAutobuz.this,Statii102.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });`
```